# Using Blocking NIO in Java

Tags: java, nio, socketchannel

I'm just wondering if it is possible to use the SocketChannel class (with ByteBuffer) to simulate the blocking features of the regular Socket class in Java. I made two Test projects, one simulating the Client and the other simulating the Server:

Client Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    SocketChannel socket = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 6789));

    //Simulate this:
    //DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.socket().getOutputStream());
    //dos.writeInt(4);
    //dos.writeInt(6);

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    buffer.putInt(4);
    buffer.flip();
    socket.write(buffer);
    buffer.clear();
    buffer.putInt(6);
    buffer.flip();
    socket.write(buffer);
}
```

Server Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ServerSocketChannel ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    ssc.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(6789));
    SocketChannel socketCh = ssc.accept();
    socketCh.configureBlocking(true);
    // Simulate this
    // DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socketCh.socket().getInputStream());
    // System.out.println(dis.readInt());
    // System.out.println(dis.readInt());

    // This is something to avoid. This is not the same as what is up above
    // If the 2nd line prints -1, the 3rd prints 4
    // If the 2nd line prints 4, the 3rd prints 6
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    socketCh.read(buffer);
    buffer.rewind();
    System.out.println("First number: " + buffer.getInt());
    buffer.clear();
    System.out.println("Change: " + socketCh.read(buffer));
    buffer.rewind();
    System.out.println("Second Number: " + buffer.getInt());
}
```

As I said in the comments, the results of running the Server then the Client (in that order) are unpredictable, since sometimes the second number might remain as 4 or become 6, with the Change being -1 or 4(bytes in Integer) respectively.

As for the server side, I know I can make it wait so that the second socketCh.read(buffer) returns a value other than -1, which means nothing was written (I presume) in the SocketChannel.

However, on the client side, I don't have any ideas.

I am aware that I can instead use DataOutputStream and DataInputStream and do it the old fashioned way, but I want to know how to do it with SocketChannels simply for convenience. Also you can't go wrong with another trick up your sleeve.

Even though I manually configured the server as blocking, I assume it's the default configuration so it's ok to discard it.

Thank you in advance!
PS: Hopefully I could avoid using the Selector classes for such a simple task...

EDIT: I know that the Selector classes can only be used for non-blocking mode.

Answer (score 1):

You're throwing away extra data that may have been read, and assuming that each read delivers exactly what corresponds to each write (for example that the first one delivers only the `int`). There is nothing in TCP that guarantees that.

Change the `rewind()` to `flip()`; change the `clear()` to `compact()`; add some checking of the return value of `read()`; and it should work as expected.

You can't use `Selector` in blocking mode.

Comment: Alright thanks! Yeah I am aware that you can't use Selector in blocking mode, however I wished to avoid having to configure the SocketChannel to non-blocking and having to do all that for just this simple task.

Comment: Makes a whole ton more sense now that I read what compact() does in detail. That's what I get for skimming over a book I guess :\. Thanks man, really appreciate it